# How do I grab the string and adjacent number in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run a loop to group the text by certain criteria and add up a total, but I need to be able to grab both bits of data.

```
Connecticut     624
Georgia         818
Washington      10
Arkansas        60
New Jersey      118
Ohio            2,797
```

The selection would be something like that, and I want the user to be able to highlight the two columns and I will run through and group the States by location and add the totals

edit--

So far, all I've been able to do is grab what the user selected range is:

```
Sub Short()
    Dim rngMyRange As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rngMyRange = Selection
    Else
        Exit Sub        'Non-range type selection e.g. a chart
    End If

    MsgBox "The address of rngMyRange is " & rngMyRange.Address(False, False)



End Sub
```

I have a formula in another sheet that checks the states for their group, but it's one cell at a time

```
=IF( AND(D9="", B9="USA"),"",IF(B9="USA",IF(COUNTIF(Legends!$B$4:$B$13,D9)>0,"US Group 1",IF(COUNTIF(Legends!$F$4:$F$15,D9)>0,"US Group 3","US Group 2")),IF(COUNTIF(Legends!$H$4:$H$6,B9)>0,"Int'l Tier 1",IF(COUNTIF(Legends!$J$4:$J$15,B9)>0,"Int'l Tier 2","Int'l Tier 3"))))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the user to be able to highlight the two columns and I will run through and group the States by location and add the totals"? I fail to see a clear direction. After all, you should try it for yourself at first. If you encounter problems with your programming, you can ask regarding questions here

Comment: @EngJon Each of the states belongs to a specific group - I need to check to see if the state belongs in that group then keep a running total for each group. Ie - Washington and New Jersey are both in Group 1, so the total would be Group 1 - 128. But the list of states and totals are different each time, so I want to be able to grab the selection of columns/rows and then do the calculations. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Look at something like looping through your state names and then using `.offset(0,1)` to get the value next to it and do whatever you want. If you can update your post with code that you've already tried we can take a look at it

Comment: @Tom I've added some pre existing code .. like it says, all I can really do now is grab the user selected range... I've got a formula I use in another sheet but that only works one cell at a time

Answer (score 1):

Using the for loop below will loop through each cell in your range (selection - make sure you select just the column with the names in it)

```
Sub Short()
    Dim rngMyRange As Range
    Dim ttl as integer
    Dim c

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rngMyRange = Selection
    Else
        Exit Sub        'Non-range type selection e.g. a chart
    End If

    for each c in rngMyRange
        ttl = ttl + c.offset(0,1)
    next c
End Sub
```

You'll need to change the for loop with your criteria. This could be done a lot easier though by using a pivot table on your data range.

Comment: Thanks, this will help!

The Pivot Table I don't think will - it won't let me sort the States by their grouping...

Comment: @Kevin It should do if you lay it out correctly. If you put the states in a row field, and their 'values' in the values field, and select to sum them it will group all the states together and give display the totals of that group